# Mac software to open a 16GB SQL file?

Tags: macos, mac, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VERY large text files and Snow Leopard](https://superuser.com/questions/138474/very-large-text-files-and-snow-leopard)
>   [Open massive file on Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/181785/open-massive-file-on-mac)

I have a 16GB sql database backup I have just taken, what software can I open it with for Mac?

I have tried TextMate, but that just fails completely by just opening a blank page and not attempting to open it. Any software will do (raw text/UI).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the SQL file was not created on that Mac, and depending on what you want to do with its data: just install the database software on that Mac, and import it into that new database?

Answer (score 4):

There's a [Vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) that allows it to open large files.

Then you could either go with the CLI version already installed or use [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/).

Answer (score 3):

How about:

`less file.sql`

from a terminal window?  You can also use grep, etc.

Note that you can't edit with `less`. For navigating the file you can use arrow keys, <kbd>space</kbd> to scroll to the next page, <kbd>b</kbd> to go back one page. With <kbd>/</kbd> you can enter a search and then use <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd> to jump between results, and finally press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit. Starting with `less -S file.sql` doesn't wrap lines and might be useful for SQL files with really long lines. All commands and options are explained in [less' man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=less&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).

Answer (score 3):

[HexFiend](http://www.ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) is the best application I've found for extremely large files as it does not try to store the entire file in memory. While more of a hex editor than a text editor it may be more than workable given that it works very, very quickly.

Comment: Good and super quick, if you can afford to work without line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

BBEdit can probably handle it (so should TextWrangler), but unless you really need to get inside and make some changes to the data, re-importing into the proper database management software is going to be your best bet.

Comment: In my experience TextWrangler (free) can handle large files much better than TextMate, but I haven't opened anything like 16GB with it.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal -> 'vi'