# VERY large text files and Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, text-editing

Sometimes I need to work on EXTREMELY large text files.  200-300 megs or more.

My favorite text editor on my MacBook Pro is TextMate.  However, TM chokes on very large text files.  Even ones around the 100MB mark.

Is there a text editor that can handle such files for Snow Leopard?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://superuser.com/questions/4044/what-editor-viewer-to-use-to-inspect-large-text-based-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://superuser.com/questions/34749/text-editor-for-very-big-file-windows

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952886/editing-large-files-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files

Comment: ChristopheD's suggestion is the only one of these which is OS X specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim.

The one true editor.

And this: [Open big files and work fast (from vim.wikia.com)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip611)

Answer (score 1):

If I ever have to handle big text files I always switch over to [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/). Same under the hood engine as BBEdit, but *free*. As in beer.

The one thing I would improve about TextMate would be to give it a command / insert mode like VIM (odd because the thing is inspired by emacs) and give it better large file handling ability.

Comment: TextWrangler can support up to 384MB files.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Smultron](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smultron/) with very large text files and it has worked well.

Answer (score -1):

BBEdit will work on really big files and intelligently swap in / out the portion you are working on.

EMACS also has paging.

Have you considered adding RAM?

Comment: Adding a bit of RAM isn't going to help.